# Python/Numpy: Using np.tile to tile 2D array of boolean mask arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array of boolean mask arrays:

```
maskArr = [[False, True, False, True], [False, True, True, True], [True, True, False, True]]
```

for which I am trying to use `np.tile(maskArr, (3, 1))` to get the following output:

```
[  
   [[False, True, False, True], [False, True, True, True], [True, True, False, True]],
   [[False, True, False, True], [False, True, True, True], [True, True, False, True]],
   [[False, True, False, True], [False, True, True, True], [True, True, False, True]],
]
```

but I'm getting this:

```
[[False  True False  True]
 [False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True False  True]
 [False  True False  True]
 [False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True False  True]
 [False  True False  True]
 [False  True  True  True]
 [ True  True False  True]]
```

Any suggestions for how I can fix this? It works fine with `arr = [1,2,3]`:

```
>>> np.tile([1,2,3], (3, 1))
[[1,2,3]
 [1,2,3]
 [1,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```py
x = np.tile(maskArr, (3, 1, 1))
print(x)
```

Prints:

```py
[[[False  True False  True]
  [False  True  True  True]
  [ True  True False  True]]

 [[False  True False  True]
  [False  True  True  True]
  [ True  True False  True]]

 [[False  True False  True]
  [False  True  True  True]
  [ True  True False  True]]]
```